# Custom css not over writing materialize Stylesheet

Tags: meteor, sass, materialize

Hi there how do i get my custom css to over write the materialise:materialise package for meteor . I have my style sheet in client/stylesheets/style.scss

Comment: Show us how you linked the css file, looks like you put your css before the materialize stylesheet, last loaded css overwrites.

Comment: No in meteor you dont call the css i automatically picks it up from inside the client folder

Comment: That might be the problem, that while your css is designed to override the materlaize css, perhaps the opposite is happening. There are ways to control the order of loading, either by doing it manually, or by playing with filenames or locations

Comment: rename your .css file such that it contains a number so that it bumps up to the top of the files. Meteor file loading order might have a play here. Eg. If you *.css file is called ```something.css```, rename it to ```_00_something.css```